# How to automatically create value from non existing key with a function

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

**Backgroud:**

Let's say I have a function (of course in reality that would be a more complex function):

```
def f(x):
    return str(x)
```

If I want to store values to avoid unnecessary recomputation, I can create a `dict` like this:

```
my_dict = {x: f(x) for x in range(5)}
```

But then if I don't know in advance which values I may need, for example `10`,  `my_dict[10]` obviously generates a `KeyError`.

One way around this could be:

```
my_dict = {}
def get_value(x):
    if x not in my_dict:
        my_dict[x] = f(x)
    return my_dict[x]

get_value(10)
```

**Question:**
This seems very similar to `defaultdict`: is there a way to make the intuitive (but broken) `my_dict = defaultdict(f)` work, i.e. when a key `x` doesn't exist, it should call `f(x)` instead of `f()` to create the default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can build your own `dict` data type. in your case, `__missing__` will help. if there is no key, `__missing__` method triggers your custom work. below is a simple example.

```
from collections import UserDict
class MyDict(UserDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = 2*key
        return self[key]

if __name__ == '__main__': # test
    a = MyDict((x, 2*x) for x in range(5))
    print(a)
    # {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8}
    a[5]
    # 10
    print(a)
    # {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5:10}
```

also note that `UserDict` is a wrapper around dictionary objects, making you comfortable to subclassing the dictionary data types.

check the official docs.

- [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)
- [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__)
- [`UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userdict-objects)

Comment: `UserDict` is only necessary in Python 2. If using Python 3 it is possible to inherit from dict directly `class MyDict(dict):`

Comment: `from collection import UserDict` doesn't work for me (either `No module named collection` (instead of `collections`?) or `cannot import name UserDict`, but using plain `dict` as base for `MyDict` works nicely!

Comment: fixed the typo, `collection` to `collections` ;]

Comment: What about `UserDict`? Is there anything special about it? (I'm in Python2 and it doesn't seem to exist...)

Comment: @robru AFAIK, the reason is that subclassing the built-in data type (like `dict` or `list`) does not call special methods overridden by user-defined classes. `collections.UserDict` (or `UserList`) is a wrapper for the `dict` built-in, resolving the overwritten method usage.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__), you might be able to get the behavior you want by subclassing `defaultdict` and overriding `__missing__`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class betterdefault(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.default_factory(key)
```

Now, you'd want to flesh that out with a little extra logic, eg throw `KeyError` if `self.default_factory` is None, stuff like that which they mention in the docs. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Here's a quick [demo](https://repl.it/JFCp)

Comment: This is pretty cool, but `__missing__` doesn't set any value. Maybe add a call to `self.setitem(key, self.default_factory(key))`?

Comment: Nice team work guys! Waiting to see if anyone comes with a simpler solution before accepting.

Comment: @Julien well, using `setdefault` *is simpler* ;) But in all seriousness, I like the above solution a lot.